# Why I get Timedelta type when access MySQL by pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

The data type in MySQL is `time`,but when I access it by pandas, the type in dataframe become `Timedelta`.
My code is

```
df = pandas.read_sql_query(“select * from table1”, con=newConnect)
```

Comment: Did you try to search on [this website](http://google.com)?

Comment: The google is banned, I can not search it in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `timedelta` is the closest to MySQL's `time` data type in Pandas/Numpy.

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
In [306]: df
Out[306]:
       time
0  10:11:12
1  22:23:24

In [307]: df.dtypes
Out[307]:
time    object
dtype: object
```

you can either convert it to `datetime` (this will require a date part):

```
In [308]: pd.to_datetime(df.time)
Out[308]:
0   2018-06-19 10:11:12
1   2018-06-19 22:23:24
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]  # <---- note the dtype
```

or to a `timedelta`:

```
In [309]: pd.to_timedelta(df.time)
Out[309]:
0   10:11:12
1   22:23:24
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]  # <---- note the dtype
```